# Is there a way to call a Solidity function by its string name?

Tags: solidity

Since functions are not first-class objects in Solidity, is there any way to invoke a dynamically-determined function at runtime? e.g.

```
string fname = "Bar";

function Foo() {
  InvokeByName(fname);
}

function Bar() {
  // do something
}
```

Please respond regarding the *feasibility* and disregard *security* for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but with some limitations.

You can call a function based on its ABI, so in your case

```
this.call(bytes4(sha3("Bar()")));
```

will call the Bar function of your contract. If the function takes an argument, you can add it to the call like so:

```
this.call(bytes4(sha3("Bar(int256)")), 42);
```

The only limitation to this is that you cannot return a value from this function, it only returns true, or false if it hits an exception.

You could use a global `result` variable, though.

In terms of security, it really depends on the context but be careful using `msg.sender` for authentication -- you may want to use `callcode` or `delegatecall` depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you! The duplicate that was marked is very useful, too: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3342/pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-solidity