# How to import a contract in another one without using import but using the address in different files?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

How to import a contract in another one without using import but using the address of that particular contract and accessing its functions and variables in different files in Solidity?

Answer (score 8):

Here's how an [example of 2 contracts in 1 file](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/basic-example-of-interaction-between-2-contracts) can be split into 2 files:

C1.sol has:

```
contract C1 {
    function f1() returns(uint) {
        return(10);
    }
}
```

C2.sol has:

```
contract C1 { function f1() returns(uint) {} }
contract C2 {
    function f2(address addrC1) returns(uint) {
        C1 c1 = C1(addrC1);
        return c1.f1();
    }
}
```

C2.sol does **need to have a stub (abstract contract code) of C1**, so that the compiler knows the functions/interface of C1.

Answer (score 3):

When you instantiate a contract with its address as parameter, then you have access to this very contract:

```
contract C1 {

  function call (address myContractsAddress, uint aParameter) returns(uint){
    C2 c2= new C2(myContractsAddress);
    return c2.aFunction(aParameter);
  }
}

contract C2 {
  function aFunction(uint aParameter) returns(uint) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Roland that's right but can i use it without importing a contract into another and just by using the address i can let a contract know which one i am using just by giving address possible or not ?example i have two contracts in different files and i want to use one in another for certain functionalities.

Comment: At least you need to know the type of contract, i.e. calling the right constructor. I edit it accordingly.

Comment: But you want to call the other contract without knowing what type of contract it is right? I've seen this somewhere...

Comment: yup exactly..i don't want to use import just by the address ,like if i know the address of that particular contract.

Comment: a trace to the solution could be that you can execute ABI code that you send to the contract before: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4124/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-solidity-function-by-its-string-name

Comment: @RolandKofler contract C2 doesn't have a constructor with argument. Possibly it will throw error at compile time. I checked it in online solidity browser. May be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the address and function signature of the other contract, you can `call` based on it's address. The [solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html) have an example:

```
address nameReg = 0x72ba7d8e73fe8eb666ea66babc8116a41bfb10e2;
nameReg.call(bytes4(sha3("fun(uint256)")), a);
```

Note that the last line generates the hex of the function signature which you could precompute...

```
nameReg.call('0x7a9839c2', a);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. Importing contracts is exactly the way to inform the compiler that functions the other address have. A pure address may only contains EVM bytecode but it is impossible to recreate high-level API out of it.

There are ideas to publish contracts' interface descriptions next to the blockchain but nothing of that has been done yet.