# cannot call internal function via `call`

Tags: internal-transactions

I have a simple test contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Test {
  uint public myVal;

  function callIt() {
      this.call.gas(50000)(bytes4(sha3("setMyVal(uint256)")), 123);
  }

  function setMyVal(uint _newVal) internal {
      myVal = _newVal;
  }
}
```

I am testing the contract in [remix](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.10+commit.f0d539ae.js). It seems that I cannot call the `setMyVal` from `callIt` if `setMyVal` is set to `internal` - why? I am still calling it from within the same contract. Is the signature in that case different from `bytes4(sha3("setMyVal(uint256)"))`?

FYI: All works well when removing the `internal` keyword. But I would like to not allow these functions to be called from the outside. In case it matters: I am looking at using this pattern similar to function pointers, similarly as discussed [before](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3358/16).

Comment: I happened across this question, and I'm curious what was the benefit of using an external call rather than just calling the function? I see you're limiting the gas... but within the same contract, I can't imagine why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two kinds of function call in Solidity which are very different.

1. *Internal* calls happen via a `JUMP` command and can be used with any function not marked `external`. These are far cheaper than external calls and mantain things like `msg.sender`, `msg.gas`, `calldata`, etc. Internal calls can only happen *within* a contract, and can access functions marked `internal`
2. *External* function calls happen either via a transaction from an "externally-owned account" or via the `CALL` opcode, and rely on the ABI interface to dispatch the call to the correct function. These kinds of call change the sender, calldata, value, etc. They cannot reach `internal` functions.

If you want to be able to call functions using the `CALL` method, you should leave the functions public, but create a modifier to disallow calls from other addresses.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Test {
  uint public myVal;

  modifier onlySelf(){
      if (msg.sender != address(this)) throw;
      _;
  }

  function callIt() {
      this.call.gas(50000)(bytes4(sha3("setMyVal(uint256)")), 123);
  }

  function setMyVal(uint _newVal) onlySelf {
      myVal = _newVal;
  }
}
```

Comment: The `onlySelf` modifier is a great solution! But still I'd prefer an abstraction and I'd love to discuss if there are better ways: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/15711/16

Answer (score 2):

*If I'm not mistaken*, `this.call ...` makes the call external. Yes, it will coincidentally originate from the same address but it's going to arrive in the form of an external message. Calling a function *within* the same contract will not create such a message.

I simplified that with

```
bool s = setMyVal(newVal);
```

This is a more idiomatic way to call the internal function.

I added a log and some return values to help expose what's going on. You can pass a value into "doIt", so named because it's going to do something.

I see you're trying to pass 50,000 gas. The following way will *send it all* and then get the remainder back; usually acceptable in an "internal" call situation.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Test {
  uint public myVal;

  event LogNewVal(bool success, uint newVal);

  function doIt(uint newVal) returns(bool success) {
      bool s = setMyVal(newVal);
      LogNewVal(s, newVal);
      return true;
  }

  function setMyVal(uint _newVal) internal returns(bool success){
      myVal = _newVal;
      return true;
  }
}
```

In Remix to show it working.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense but I like to have the functionality of only knowing the function at run-time, hence the other option. Probably out of scope for this question, hence I started another: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/15711/16