# How to type-cast a function pointer in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, data-types, type-casting, function-pointer

I have a function that takes a parameter of type `function (uint256) view returns (uint256)`.

I want to pass it a pointer to a function of type `function (uint256) pure returns (uint256)`.

Obviously there shouldn't be a problem with passing this `pure` function into a parameter that expects a `view` function, because the parameter and returns types are the same and `pure` is even more limiting than `view`. However, I get this TypeError:

> TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid
>   implicit conversion from `function (uint256) pure returns (uint256)` to
>   `function (uint256) view returns (uint256)` requested.

Things I've tried:

**Assigning the function to a local variable gives a similar TypeError:**

```
function(uint256) view returns(uint256) a = func;
```

> TypeError: Type `function (uint256) pure returns (uint256)` is not implicitly convertible to expected type `function (uint256) view returns (uint256)`

**The usual type-casting syntax of Solidity gives a ParserError at the `function` keyword**

```
function(uint256) view returns(uint256) a = function(uint256) view returns(uint256)  (func);
```

> ParserError: Expected primary expression

**-------**

I've noticed that the TypeError's keep telling me that the function pointer is not `implicitly` convertible. Is there a way to explicitly convert it?

Comment: What operation do you want to do that this work is necessary for it?

Comment: I have a higher-order function that takes a `view` function as parameter. I want to pass it a `pure` function.

Comment: The main question is that what operation makes you to pass a function as a parameter to another function? Isn't it possible to do it in ordinary methods?

Comment: Yes, I could inline the code of my higher order function wherever it is called, but I don't want to duplicate that code everywhere. My situation is: I have a non-fungible token with a bunch of dynamically calculated properties (implemented as view or pure functions). Some of those properties are actually just combinations of other properties. For example, property G might be true only if ((A or B) and (C+D+E+F >= 6)) is true. To compute G I don't necessarily need all of A-F, so I combine the property functions using higher-order functions that implement short-cutting behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:
In recent Solidity versions, pure function pointers are now implicitly convertible to view function pointers.**

I did not find a solution to this problem, so I submitted an issue on Github: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/4349

I did find two ways to work around the problem:

1: Downgrade all my pure functions to view.

2: Use inline assembly to assign to a local variable, thereby circumventing the Solidity type system:

```
function(uint256)view returns(uint256) a;
assembly { a := func }
```

Answer (score -4):

I cannot understand your point.

In solidity they do not exist function pointers, because the calling mechanism is to pass the control to the *smart contract* which owns the function and to use ABI table to jump there to the function first instruction.

So there is not a *pointer* to a function you can use like you do in C!

In Solidity the address of any function IS the ethereum addess of its smart contract

I.e. in a qualitative way, the *address (function foo())* is the address of the smart contract implementing foo()

May be I did not understand properly your question!

---

EDIT AFTER COMMENTS

Typecast cannot be applied to function type, as far as I know only implicit conversion can be done and this IS the demonstration that the function pointer as lvalue DO NOT EXISTS.

From [solidity docs:](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#function-types)

"A value of external function type can be explicitly converted to address resulting in the address of the contract of the function.

A function type A is implicitly convertible to a function type B if and only if their parameter types are identical, their return types are identical, their internal/external property is identical and the state mutability of A is not more restrictive than the state mutability of B. In particular:

pure functions can be converted to view and non-payable functions
view functions can be converted to non-payable functions
payable functions can be converted to non-payable functions

**No other conversions between function types are possible.**"

Anyway if we are here to learn, so I hope to learn something new from you soon.

Check also [function as parameter](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3342/pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-solidity)

Comment: You are talking about external functions, my question is about function pointers for internal functions. For those, there certainly are pointers to internal functions like in C.

Comment: Yes, they exist local addresses equal to the first instruction of any function, but you cannot extract them by high level language (Solidity), neither use typecast on them!

Comment: Suppose you have an internal pure function: `function testFunc(uint256 x) internal pure returns (uint256 y) { return x+5; }`

Now you can put its function pointer in a local variable with the appropriate type: `function(uint256) internal pure returns (uint256) func = testFunc;`

And you can call the function via its function pointer: `func(345)`

Comment: My question is about the ability to cast a function pointer of type `function (uint256) internal pure returns (uint256)` to type `function (uint256) internal view returns (uint256)`. Do you understand now?

Comment: Also, please don't speak so certainly about something you don't know. It's very rude.

Comment: You are on the wrong part of the hill. I edit the answer to add what I know.

Comment: When I asked the question, no conversions between function pointer types were possible, not even implicit conversions. I created a github issue & submitted a pull request. It was implemented and now pure function pointers are implicitly convertible to view functions. (I wrote the code that added that feature) I don't understand on which hill you think I am on the wrong side of.

Comment: I do not understand your point. You are asking about explicit (I.e. by typecast) conversion or about implicit (I.e. without typecast) conversion? I do not think that function pointer is an ivalue. Is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91018/discussion-between-rick-park-and-jesse-busman).