# Passing functions as parameters: How to invoke?

Tags: solidity

I found one link for my question at: [2016 Link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3342/pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-solidity)

I have got the following code from:[link](https://medium.com/coinmonks/gas-cost-of-solidity-library-functions-dbe0cedd4678)

```
function GasCost(string memory name, 
    function () internal returns (string memory) fun) 
    internal returns (string memory) 
{
    uint u0 = gasleft();
    string memory sm = fun();
    uint u1 = gasleft();
    uint diff = u0 - u1;
    return concat(name, " GasCost: ", stringOfUint(diff), 
                " returns(", sm, ")");
}
```

Somebody please explain me what is the name of the above function defining technique?  and how to invoke the function GasCost(...) and how to define fun? Provide me the link for the tutorial also.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are named [function types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#function-types). I don't know if the technique has a particular name.

Here is an example where the function are used as primitive sort of dispatcher.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract A {

    enum Action { Walk, Fly, Swim }

    function walk() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 10;
    }

    function fly() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 50;
    }

    function swim() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 20;
    }

    function cost(function () internal pure returns (uint) activity) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return activity();
    }

    function foo(Action action) public pure returns (uint) {
        function () internal pure returns (uint) activity;
        if (action == Action.Swim) {
            activity = swim;
        } else if (action == Action.Fly) {
            activity = fly;
        } else {
            activity = walk;
        }

        return cost(activity);
    }
}
```

---

Edit: You could invoke `GasCost` with something like this:

```
function ComplexFunction() internal returns (string memory) {
   return "Echo";
}

function Caller(string memory name) public returns (string memory) {
   return GasCost(name, ComplexFunction);
}
```

Comment: thanks,first argument of GasCost(...) function is 'name', can you please tell me what is the name of 2nd argument in case of GasCost(...) function and how to invoke the GasCost(...) function?

Comment: @zak100 The type is `function () internal returns (string memory)` and the name is `fun`. See the edit for an example how to use GasCost.